# Tailwind Image Background Using url() in React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using React and Tailwind to build an app. I'm trying to set an image background for a div element using url() but it's not working. I've shared my code below. The project directory setup is the default when using create-react-app, **however, I have added an "images" folder in the public folder where i'm storing the image to be used by the div element in question.**

```
function App() {
  return <div className='h-screen w-screen bg-[url("/images/illustration-hero.svg")]'></div>;
}
```

I found the following code sample from Tailwind's website and need to do exactly this:

```
<div class="bg-[url('/img/hero-pattern.svg')]">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Kindly help me solve this issue...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the background image because you need the absolute path to the image if we use the `background-image` property. Reload **CRA** after changes.

###### Folder structure

```txt
/public
  /images
    illustration-hero.svg
  index.html
  ...
/src
  App.css
  App.js
  index.css
  index.js
  ...
package.json
tailwind.config.js
...
```

```js
function App() {
  return <div className='h-screen w-screen bg-[url("../public/images/illustration-hero.svg")]'></div>;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're solution is working perfectly. If I try to load the same image using an <img/> tag things are working a little differently. I typed the following code and its working:             return (
    <div className='h-screen w-screen'>
      <img src='/images/image-equilibrium.jpg' />
    </div>
  );                Can you please explain why the path in the <img/> tag is working...Do img tags accept relative paths too??

Comment: Sorry for the messed up code...I dont know how to edit it properly and insert line breaks in the comments...

Comment: This is a **webpack** config for the img tag, so you don't need to provide an absolute path and it automatically binds to the public folder. When we want to use an image with inline style (css), **webpack** doesn't know about it, in this case we need to provide an absolute path to bind our image to the inline style.